# Правила установки qmake

Tags: qt, qmake

Вот часть .pro-файла, в которой перечислены файлы для установки.

```
install_it.path = $$OUT_PWD/../Deploy
install_it.files = sgip/sgip.json sgip/psi.tpl sgip/sgip_template.json \
    sgip_sokol_dll/usb_sgip_dll/release/usb_sgip_dll.dll \
    sgip/release/sgip.exe \
    $$PWD/sgip/3rdparty/postgres/bin/*
```

#

```
install_qtbin.path = $$OUT_PWD/../Deploy
install_qtbin.files = $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]/icu* \
    $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]/libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll \
    $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]/libstdc++-6.dll \
    $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]/libwinpthread-1.dll \
    $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]/Qt5Concurrent.dll \
    $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]/Qt5Core.dll \
    $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]/Qt5Gui.dll \
    $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]/Qt5PrintSupport.dll \
    $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]/Qt5Widgets.dll \
    $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]/Qt5Sql.dll

install_img.path = $$OUT_PWD/../Deploy/img
install_img.files = ../img/*
```

#

```
install_sqldrivers.path = $$OUT_PWD/../Deploy/sqldrivers
install_sqldrivers.files = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/sqldrivers/qsqlpsql.dll

INSTALLS += \
    install_it \
    install_img \
    install_qtbin \
    install_sqldrivers
```

Проблемы две. Во-первых, не копируется файл libstdc++-6.dll. Файл существует, но скопировать его не получается: утилита copy возвращает ошибку "Файл не найден". Если в командной строке выполнить ту же команду, та же ошибка. Если в имени файла в командной строке указать libstdc*, то файл копируется нормально, однако в .pro-файле такой трюк не работает, так как в Makefile в итоге попадает полное имя файла. Как можно это исправить?

Второе. Если тот или иной файл не существует на момент выполнения qmake, то в Makefile этот файл не попадёт. Но некоторые файлы, например, sgip.exe или usb_sgip_dll.dll создаются на этапе выполнения make, поэтому совершенно не важно, существуют они при выполнении qmake или нет. Как заставить qmake помещать эти файлы в makefile в любом случае?

**UPD**

Обнаружил, что утилита xcopy копирует этот файл правильно. После ручной замены параметров COPY, INSTALL_FILE и др. в Makefile проект установился без ошибок. Но хотелось бы, чтобы qmake сам подставлял утилиту xcopy в Makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение одной из проблем. В qmake есть недокументированные переменные, которые как раз подходят для того, чтобы заменить команды копирования файлов. Добавив в .pro-файл следующие строки, я получил желаемое поведение.

```
QMAKE_COPY = xcopy /y
QMAKE_INSTALL = xcopy /y
```

Вопрос с принудительным добавлением файлов в правила установки остаётся открытым.